# Using data-ajax tag inside PHP code

Tags: php, jquery-mobile

I am using the code proposed by Dreamweaver to open an URL after creating a record using a form. This is the PHP code that does it:

```
  $insertGoTo = "registroOK.html";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    $insertGoTo .= (strpos($insertGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
    $insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  }
  header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));
```

In my web site I am using JQuery Mobile and normally I use the tag data-ajax='false' inside the `<a href>` tag when I want to go to an external file, but I don't know how to implement this inside the PHP code that defines the URL to open.

Comment: External file ? Internal file ? Why don't you check for the existence of `http` in URL ?

Comment: @Raptor, what do you mean? The file is in the same folder.

Comment: do you understand what does your PHP code mean?

Comment: @Raptor, I think this code opens the file 'registroOK.html' in the browser when the user finishes to enter the needed information in the form and presses the submit button.

Comment: @Raptor, I have solved the issue, please take a look at my answer, the problem had nothing to do with PHP. Thank you.

Comment: Glad you solved the problem. But the PHP logic does not work as you think. It just appends the query string, if exists, to the `registroOK.html` and forward to the updated URL. Nothing to do with form submission.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was not a PHP issue. It was a JQM issue, which is solved putting this on every page head section:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
    $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
});
</script>
```

Thank you for your time and effort.